# Can Any one with understanding of this syntax?

Tags: javascript

How are these two things different? I know that 2nd line will work but some methods work fine will line 1 ( similar Methods ),

```
varAbc.textContent("Value");
varAbc.textContent = "Value";
```

Comment: I fail to see any situation in which the first example "works". `textContent` is not a function.

Comment: Let's say `varAbc` is some object with a `textContent` method (or more accurately, a textContent property which points to a function/method). So calling it "works". You can also assign some other value - in your case a string literal - to that property, replacing the pointer. Now it evaluates to that string literal.

Answer (score 0):

varAbc is an `object` in both cases. Only the difference is that `textContent` in line 1 is a method, while it is a property in line 2.

***Case 1***

```
var varAbc = {
  textContent : function (arg) {
   console.log(arg); // "Value"
  }
}
```

***Case 2***

```
var varAbc = {
  textContent : "Value"
  }
}
```